# Alternatives to Adobe Shadow

Tags: html

Adobe Shadow was a product released by adobe labs. It connected the desktop browser with mobile devices, such that all mobile devices navigate in sync when browsing on the desktop browser. This was very useful. This product is discontinued and now part of Adobe Edge (http://blogs.adobe.com/edgeinspect/2012/09/23/shadow-is-now-adobe-edge-inspect/) requiring a paid adobe creative cloud subscription.

Question: **Are there alternatives to Adobe Shadow?**

Is there a special stackexchange forum for web design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple alternative you can try BrowSync.
http://browsync.net

Comment: I should also mention that I am also author of the BrowSync.

Comment: Also as a "should mention" is that this requires a $1.99 app as well.

Comment: You can use BrowSync for free. Simply open [browsync.net/client](http://browsync.net/client) on your device. For your convinience save the page to your homescreen.

Comment: Unfortunately this product appears to have been discontinued. If you click on the above link you get a spammy lottery page.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out Muir, has desktop clients for Mac and Windows and covers iOS, Android, Nook HD and Kindle HD Devices.

http://labs.iqfoundry.com/muir/

Comment: Heads up to people going to install this. The mobile app required to make this work is $4.99 per device.

Answer (score 2):

Ghostlab is another good alternative, tests on real mobile/desktop browsers and also syncs scrolls, form inputs, clicks and DOM inspection.

http://ghostlab.vanamco.com/

Comment: Note: This is a free 7 day trial.

Answer (score 0):

found an open source project, not as convenient as Adobe Shadow tough:

https://github.com/viljamis/Remote-Preview

Comment: plug it doesn't let you inspect them.